# Apachi mod_wsgi handler for Python not "executing", but merely show source code only

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to use python to serve web pages, and I'm using Apache In Windows 7, and mod_wsgi. I Installed everything correctly, I got the Apache "It works!" page fine.

I followed the instructions in the page below.

I'm using 64 bit Windows 7, Apache 64 bit, mod_wsgi also 64 bit.

http://pradyumnajoshi.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/setting-up-mod_wsgi-for-apache-and-django-on-windows/

But once I point it to the python file like.

```
http://localhost:8081/test.py
```

[image]

It displays the source code without executing it. Can anyone tell me where did I do the screw up in the installation ? Did  mod_wsgi is the issue here or python ? version issues ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but can you please use `return` instead of `print` and check if this works

Comment: definitely after putting this bunch of code to a method.

Comment: You don't seem to have understood that blog entry at all. mod_wsgi is for serving a WSGI application, not a standalone Python script.

Comment: did u import following packages    import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()